# Creating a vector with n elements in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, stdvector

If I just write this code:

```
std::vector<int> vec(24, 3);
```

It'll create a vector called vec with 24 elements all equal to 3.
But if I have a struct:

```
struct Day
{
    std::vector<int> days(24, 3);
};
```

And try to do the exact same thing it doesn't work, why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax would be:

```
struct Day
{
    vector<int> days = vector<int>(24, 3);
};
```

You cannot call constructor with `()` syntax there (to avoid [vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) (but can with `{}`or `= /*...*/`).

Comment: A little unfortunate we can't use the `= {...};` syntax in this case.

Comment: @aschepler: syntax `= {..}` is valid [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xzb971he3). but `{3, 3, 3, 3,.. 3}` seems less appropriate than `vector<int>(24, 3)`.

Comment: Okay, yes. We *can* use the braces, if the size is constant and not huge. But we don't want to do that rewrite.

Comment: And the Most Vexing Parse has nothing to do with this one - there's no parse of `(24, 3)` as a function parameter list. Parentheses just aren't a permitted initializer syntax for a member declaration within the class.

Comment: @aschepler: That interdiction has been done to avoid possible vexing parsing issues (even if there is none here).

Comment: Agree, I see what you meant by that now.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct Day
> {
>     std::vector<int> days(24, 3);
> };
> ```

As already mentioned in the other answer, you can't call the constructor with `()`, as that syntax would trigger the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

In fact, `days` would be interpreted as the declaration of a *member function* `Day::days()`, returning a `std::vector<int>`, and taking two parameters. However, the type of these parameters is not specified, so you get a compile-time error.

It's interesting to note that you *may* think of calling the constructor using the *uniform initialization* syntax with curly braces `{}`:

```
struct Day
{
    std::vector<int> days{24, 3};  // Pay attention!
};
```

This code does compile; but it creates a *wrong* vector, not what you expected. In fact, it creates a vector containing the two integer numbers 24 and 3. This is because this syntax invokes the `std::vector` constructor taking an initializer list, not the *(element count, element value)* constructor overload you meant.

So, a valid option is to use the more verbose syntax:

```
struct Day
{
    std::vector<int> days = std::vector<int>(24, 3);
};
```